# Conditional. Prioritize one field over another if both exist

Tags: conditionals

Cannot seem to work this out!

I have two fields, one is an image {e_image} and the other is plain text {e_map}.
Both of these display a div in the exact same spot.

What I want, is if an image is uploaded to the {e_image} field, AND text is added to the {e_map} field, then ONLY the image will appear (it is prioritised over the map {e_map) field). Both cannot appear on the page.

So something like below:

```
{if e_image}
 <div>{e_image}</div>
{if:elseif e_map}
 <div>{e_map}</div>
{/if}
```

And obviously if both fields are left empty, nothing appears.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your demo code is already perfect for what you want.

Comment: Thanks, was however having an issue which I have noted below. May be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
{if e_image}
 <div>{e_image}</div>
{if:elseif e_map && ! e_image}
 <div>{e_map}</div>
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks this works... however it appears to have the same issue as with the example code i pasted. Both fields have content, but to test I remove the image from the field - which should then only display the map. However nothing then appears, as if the map field has no content.
I re-save the entry (making no change) and then the map appears. 
Strange, but maybe some kind of bug. 
I guess I can live with it though as the possibility of the image having to be removed would be minimal.

Comment: Just a minor thing but might fix the problem - you don't need the `&& ! e_image` in the second conditional as is already covered by the `{if:elseif}`.  Removing the redundant second test for `e_image` might help with the logic bug you are seeing.